# Taking a high quality image through default camera activity and saving it o the sd card

Tags: android, android-camera

I am taking a high resolution picture through the default camera activity(using `intent.put Extras`),and saving it to the sd card,

**Code:**

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button takepicture ;
    ImageView iv ;
    TextView tv;
    Button show;

    String filepath;
    Intent i;
    Uri mUri;

    final static int cameraData = 0;

    File folder = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        takepicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        takepicture.setOnClickListener(this);
        show.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.button1:

            String sdcardstate = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();

            if(sdcardstate.contentEquals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){

                 filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

                 folder = new File(filepath,"wax");

                 if(!folder.exists()){
                     try {
                        folder.createNewFile();
                         Log.d("folder created", "ya");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }

                 mUri = Uri.fromFile(folder);
                 Log.d("bk", mUri.toString());

                 i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                 i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);

                 Log.d("extra", "extra");
                 startActivityForResult(i,cameraData);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.button2:

            File f = new File(filepath,"bmp.png");

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());              

            iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);                
            break;
        }           
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

            tv.setText("Result ok");
            Log.d("ok", "ok");
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        }
    }
}
```

The camera activity starts , the image is taken , But when i click save , it does not return and force closes.

I have read quite a few threads on this , Learnt that file must be created before the camera activity is started , but still it does not.

Please help , I'm stuck on this problem for a week or so.

Logcat error

```
06-15 16:05:50.205: W/dalvikvm(1780): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-15 16:05:50.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1780): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 12
06-15 16:05:50.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1780): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
06-15 16:05:50.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:760)
06-15 16:05:50.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:916)
06-15 16:05:50.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1246)
06-15 16:05:50.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1780):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)
06-15 16:05:50.294: W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.android.camera/.Camera
06-15 16:05:50.444: V/camera(1780): stopPreview
```

Comment: I am testing it on a device ,even then i will place the emulator logcat,

Comment: Do you know that you can debug apps on real device? It's much easier than emulator :)

Comment: i DO know that , But somehow the device's drivers are not getting installed on my PC .. SO cant help

Comment: and...what's "high quality" from your question have to do with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following to achieve this.

Before you call CameraIntent create a file and uri based on that filepath as shown here.

```
filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test/testfile.jpg";
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filename));

// start default camera
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                imageUri);
startActivityForResult (cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Now, you have the filepath you can use it in onAcityvityResult method as following,

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode != CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST || filename == null)
        return;
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    img.setImageURI(imageUri);
}
```

Comment: great , I have tried this earlier , it didnot work for me ,But it did this tym , i dont know wats the error but never mind , it worked CheerS!!;)

Comment: Just 1 more thing , when setting the image to the imageview , it is set in the landscape whereeas i want it to be opposte , How can i acheive that?

Comment: The image is actually saved in the landscape even if i take it in portrait mode

Answer (score 2):

This smells like outOfMemoryException. Instead of just fetching the huge picture file directly you need to do some code magic so that it doesn't eat up all the memory. Check out some documentation here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

And some code 4 u:

```
public Bitmap decodeFile(File f, int size){
    try {

        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;

        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<size) // || height 
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all the code in Respective Try Catch Exception handling. Then debug the code and check where the exception is thrown. You might be running out of memory exception.

Follow this:

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: Do u mean because of the size of the high quality image , it might result into a memory error??

Comment: Perhaps. This can be a reason.

Comment: Isn't there any way by we can get a good quality image from the default camera activity and save it to SD card . plz have a try

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private LinearLayout view;
    private TextView photoButton, shareButton, saveButton;
    private Bitmap b, photo;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view = findViewById(R.id.view);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
        photoButton = this.findViewById(R.id.captur);

        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
                } else {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent cameraIntent = new
                        Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            //convert bitmap
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            view.buildDrawingCache(true);
            b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        }
    }
}
```