# Improve quality of programmatically captured image in the android app

Tags: android, android-camera

I integrated camera in my application and using that camera the captured image is blur. Any suggestions for improving captured image quality.
I am using multipart for sending image on server.

> Code Snippet

```
@Override
public void openCameraAction() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Constants.CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        imageBase64 = encodeToBase64(photo);

        imageUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
        imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));

        getImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),imageFile);
        MultipartBody.Part image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(imageQuestionId, imageFile.getName(),requestBody);
        parts.add(image);
    }
}

public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image)
{
    Bitmap immagex=image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imageEncoded;
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: do you want to upload the actual image taken from the camera ?

Comment: @GarrimaKakkr  check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11049378/7666442

Comment: @GarrimaKakkr and also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382217/7666442

Comment: @quick learner yes i want to upload actual image but actual scenario is the camera app integrated in the code captures image and saves in some temp folder in mobile and then sends image from there and that too captured image is blur if captured using camera integrated in the app otherwise if I normally open phone camera then image comes out to be clear.

Comment: @NileshRathod thank you

Answer (score 0):

Find a class image picker in this gist 
https://gist.github.com/r00786/2c9aa88b706daccd55098ac2c28e7f39

all the things are handled in this class

How to use

```
 private static final int PICK_IMAGE_ID = 234; // the number doesn't matter

  public void onPickImage(View view) {
    Intent chooseImageIntent = ImagePicker.getPickImageIntent(this);
    startActivityForResult(chooseImageIntent, PICK_IMAGE_ID);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case PICK_IMAGE_ID:
            Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this, resultCode, data);
            // TODO use bitmap
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want the actual image taken camera to server u need to create
>   the image

Try this code

Delcare this Variable

```
private String actualPictureImagePath = "";
```

Then call this method on button click `cameraIntent()`

```
private void cameraIntent() {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    actualPictureImagePath = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageFileName;
    File file = new File(pictureImagePath);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);               
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
}
```

and Then in `onActivityResult()` handle this

```
@override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
        File imgFile = new  File(actualPictureImagePath);
            if(imgFile.exists()){        
          InputStream inputStream = null;//You can get an inputStream using any IO API
inputStream = new FileInputStream(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead;
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);
try {
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
output64.close();

String base64String = output.toString();

            }
        }

    }
```

**This is the code to use for Bitmap to Base64**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
          myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm 
          is the bitmap object   
          byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray(); 
          String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, 
          Base64.DEFAULT);
```

NOTE:-

**Do not forget to Add runtime permissions and in manifest also**

> 1)Read and Write Persmission
>
> 2)Camera persmission